# How to get Month Name and Year from given date?

Tags: sql-server

How can I get the name of the month and year from a given date ?

This query gets the name of the month but I want output to be like this

```
February, 2018

SELECT DATENAME(month, GETDATE()) AS 'Month Name'
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Why don't you concatenate the strings?

Comment: `SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) + ', ' + DATENAME(YEAR, GETDATE());`. Try to do a little research yourself before asking questions. If you'd have looked at the documentation for `DATENAME`, you'll have noticed your can provide other values for the 1st parameter.

Comment: `SELECT DATENAME(month, GETDATE())+', '+DATENAME(Year, GETDATE())`

Comment: You better do this on client-side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012 and later, ie in all supported versions, you can use [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) to format a value using a .NET format string :

```
select format(getdate(),'MMMM, yyyy')
```

Returns :

```
February, 2018
```

In earlier versions you'd have to concatenate individual names, eg :

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) + ', ' + DATENAME(YEAR,GETDATE())
```

To get :

```
February, 2018
```

A better approach though would be to format values *on the **client***, by setting, eg a report or form field's format string. It's easier for the client or the report creator to know the correct format and locale to use to display dates.

You can pass a locale identifier to specify the locale, eg:

```
select format(getdate(),'MMMM, yyyy','fr-FR')
```

Will return :

```
février, 2018
```

This should only be considered a workaround though.

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul the best option is to *not* format on the server but let the client/report decide

Comment: i removed my comment after seeing your uptdate, however why are you talking about server, a query is client side?

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul queries run *server-side*. On the client they are just text

Comment: i know so that's the reason why format is used in a query

Comment: personally, i would avoid using `FORMAT`, just because it runs awfully slow. Try running your `FORMAT` query and then your `DATENAME` query against a decently sized dataset (talking at least 100,000+ rows) one after the other with `SET STATISTICS TIME ON;`. You'll notice a huge difference in the execution times.

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul no that's why format should *not* be used in a query. The *results* aren't text - they have specific types. Ints are ints, dates are dates. The *client* formats the results into strings for display, either implicitly or explicitly.

Comment: @Larnu I don't think that benchmarking workarounds is useful. Formatting is the client's job

Comment: That was a comment about `FORMAT` in general. And, @PanagiotisKanavos , there can be plenty of times were you may well need to get the format in the correct way; for example during ETL processes. For reports, no do the formatting in the presentation layer, but there are definitely reasons why sometimes you do it in the queries (especially when there is no presentation layer).

Comment: @Larnu if I had 100K rows I'd use a calendar table with translations. I'm not arguing that FORMAT is fast, I'd try to avoid formatting as much as possible and in the end use the option that's easiest to maintain.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's fine, but that wasn't the point of my comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) + ', ' + CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4))
```

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT DATENAME(DD, GETDATE()) + ', ' + DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) +
> ','+  DATENAME(YEAR, GETDATE());

It will return 12 as day, August as Month and 2021 as Year.

12, August,2021